# How to Update Mysql database on live server with my local mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

Please I need help, I have an application running well on the Internet but the Network go down drastically sometimes, 
So I imported the online database to my offline version. I want to be running the offline version and update the live version on regular basis either automatically with php code  or through phpmyadmin. Please anyone with an idea of how I can  do  that should please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Check out "MySQL-Replication": https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Comment: I have done that, but don't know if it's possible to do that with an offline database

Comment: Please define "Offline Database" -- Ofc. you cannot sync a replicated database with something thats offline - But if offline means just "a disconnect every now and then" it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the local database automatically when the live server gets a chance.

**This concept calls database replication(Master Slave Model).**

You can slave your local database which doesn't need static IP. You can set it anywhere.

Master Database need must need static IP.  And you can connect as many slaves as you want with the master database.

The Master database automatically sent changes to all slaves.